# Measuring the entropy of a transition probability matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, graph, graph-theory, entropy

I'm working on a project which requires to analyze certain graph properties of transition probability matrices which are constructed as weighted directed graphs.
one of the properties of interest is the entropy of these graphs, which i have yet to find a proper way to measure, the general idea is that i need some sort of measure which allows me to quantify the extent to which a certain graph is "ordered" in order to ascertain the predictive value of the nodes within the graph (I.E if all the nodes have the exact same connection patterns, then effectively their predictive value is zero, though this is a very simplistic explanation as there are many other contributing factors to a nodes predictive power).

Iv'e experimented with certain built in matlab commands:
entropy - generally used to determine the entropy of an image
wentropy - to be honest i do not fully understand the proper use of this function, but iv'e tried using it with the 'shannon' and 'log energy' types, and have produced some incosistent results

this is a very basic script i whipped up to some testing, which produces two matrices:

- an 20*20 matrix constructed with values drawn entirely from a uniform distribution, intended to produce a matrix with a relatively low degree of order - **unordgraph**
- a 20*20 matrix constructed with 4 5*5 "patches" in which the values are integers drawn from a uniform distribution with a given range that is significantly larger than one, while the rest of the values are drawn from a uniform distribution on the range 0-1 (as in the previous matrix), this form of graph is more "ordered" than the previous patch - **ordgraph**

when i run the code:

```
clear all;

n = 50;
gsize = 20;
orderedrange = [100 200];
enttype = 'shannon';
for i = 1:n;
    unordgraph = rand(gsize);
    %     entvec(1,i) = entropy(unordgraph);
    entvec(1,i) = wentropy(unordgraph,enttype);
%     ordgraph = reshape(1:gsize^2,gsize,gsize);
    ordgraph = rand(gsize);
    ordgraph(1:5,1:5) = randi(orderedrange,5);
    ordgraph(6:10,6:10) = randi(orderedrange,5);
    ordgraph(11:15,11:15) = randi(orderedrange,5);
    ordgraph(16:20,16:20) = randi(orderedrange,5);
    %     entvec(2,i) = entropy(ordgraph);
    entvec(2,i) = wentropy(ordgraph,enttype);

end

fprintf('the mean entropy of the unordered graph is: %.4f\n',mean(entvec(1,:)));
fprintf('the mean entropy of the ordered graph is: %.4f\n',mean(entvec(2,:)));
```

i get outputs such as:

> the mean entropy of the unordered graph is: 88.8871
>
> the mean entropy of the ordered graph is: -23936552.0113

i'm not really sure about the meaning of such negative values as running the same script on a matrix comprised entirely of zeros or ones (and hence maximally ordered) produces a mean entropy of 0.

i have a pretty rudimentary background in graph theory, making this task that much more difficult, and i would be really grateful for any help, whether theoretical or algorithmical

thanks in advance,
Ron

Comment: Neither entropy() nor wentropy() know anything about transition matrices or the kind of entropy you're describing. I think you need to look at the eigenvectors of your transition matrix - maybe the entropy (-sum(log(ev/sum(ev))/log(2)) of the eigenvector with the largest eigenvalue?  This is the asymptotic distribution across the states in your graph as the transition matrix is repeatedly applied, starting from a uniform distribution across all states.

Comment: @dpwe i'm getting negative values for both matrices, how would you interpret that?

Comment: ev/sum(ev) is supposed to be a nonnegative discrete distribution with all values between zero and one, so the log of those values should all be negative, so the negative of their weighted sum should be positive. (Note, I just saw an error in my entropy expression - it should be nev = ev/sum(ev); ent = -sum(nev.*log(nev)/log(2)) )